# Using G*Power To Compare Models Using Cross-Validation

Tags: machine-learning

Has anyone used G*Power to compare models using cross-validation? If so, would calculated sample size be the number of times to execute cross-validation? My number of groups is three (three models), while my number of measurements is five (using five-fold cross-validation). Assuming these settings are correct, I an interpreting the sample size to be the number of times I have to execute CV, i.e., the number of rounds of CV?